# Is there something missing with this definition of a simplex?

Tags: algebraic-topology

In some lecture notes I'm reading and the book "Generic and Topological Inference" (by Boissonnant), the definition for a simplex is given as:

Definition 2.1 (Simplex) Given a set $P = {p_0 , . . . , p_k } \subset \mathbb R^d$ of
$k + 1$
affinely independent points, the k-dimensional simplex $\sigma$ , or k-simplex for
short, spanned by P is the set of convex combination
$$
\sum^k_i  \lambda_i p_i, \quad \text{with } \sum^k_{i=0}\lambda_i = 1 \text{ and }
\lambda_i \geq 0.
$$

Now, the issue I'm having with this definition is that it "seems" to me that if I take $\mathbb R^2$, and four points, I could say that a square is my 2-simplex in 2D. Would that be correct according the definition, or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure it's $\mathbb{R}^d$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: Yeah, I am. That's what was confusing me. But now I see that the affine indep actually restricts such dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Does there actually exist an affinely independent set of $4$ points in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Thanks, Lee. Now I see that the affinely independence restricts the size of the underlying space. The thing that was throwing me off is that people draw $2$-simplices in 2D as triangles. But if I understood correctly, it's actually a triangle in 3D.

Comment: Well, regarding triangles in 2D, does there exist an affinely independent set of 3 points in $\mathbb R^2$?